# Print/Access the Name of the Currently Executing Ant Target

Tags: ant

How do I do this within my build file?  Say I just want to `<echo/>` the name?

Comment: Yes - I made a macrodef to forward ant targets to another script and would be nice to do things like this:

    <macrodef name="call-make">
          <attribute name="target" default="@enclosing.target.name"/>
        ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no built-in property for the current executing target name. Some debate [on this is here](http://marc.info/?l=ant-dev&m=100020030007131&w=2).

If you configure ant with log4j as a listener like this, the output will display each target start and end like below. Calling `ant build`:

```
D:\apache-ant-1.8.0RC1\bin>ant -lib D:\log4j\log4j\1.2.13 -listener org.apache.tools.ant.listener.Log4jListener build
Buildfile: D:\apache-ant-1.8.0RC1\bin\build.xml
11:39:34 INFO  Build started.

build:
11:39:34 INFO  Target "build" started.
      [echo] 100
11:39:34 INFO  Updating property file: D:\abc.properties
 [propertyfile] Updating property file: D:\abc.properties
 11:39:35 INFO  Target "build" finished.

BUILD SUCCESSFUL
Total time: 0 seconds
```

Comment: Thanks for the link to the discussion, it was helpful reading to gain a perspective.  Unfortunately, I don't think a listener is what I'm after.  I had assumed that since the project name and invoked targets were get-able, the current target would be as well, and that I was just missing a property somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

I think this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17612448/366749) to pretty much the same question is more satisfactory, with a ready-to use macro to extract the value whenever necessary.